# angularJS, changing classes inside ng-repeat start - end

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I got a ng-repeat-start going on to create as many tables as needed depending on the data we get from the database/api, so one table might be worktime, one expenses, one vacation, and they get created based on if there is data in that category (no vacation? the vacation table won't get created).

Now everything works fine, got some adjustments to do, each table should have a different header color (let's say worktime is red, vacation is green and so on).

I can't figure out how can I change the header color of the panel containing the tables for each different table.

```
.WorkTable .panel-warning>.panel-heading {
border-color: #f58705;
background-color: #f58705;
}
```

this is the css code to give a specific color to the header, what's the best way to change colors for each table that gets generated?

I can't know how many tables will get generated, that depends on the user, but I know that there could be max 10 tables and I would like to define a color for each one of them, in case they get generated.

Hope the question is clear, I don't know what else I could share code-wise, because the rest of the code is irrelevant, as I need to know, in general, how you can give different classes to elements that get generated with a ng-repeat, and I can't use index because I don't know what will be generated and how many elements

edit: the data that populates the tables has an id value, so the controller knows that each ID needs a separate table, so it doesnt put all the data from the database in the same table but creates one for each different ID, that s also how I show stuff in some tables and others I don't, using:

```
ng-show="t.tableID == 0"
```

in this case, only on the table with ID = 0, things will be shown, can I use the same for the colors? assigning on each ID one different color?

edit for more clarification:

In the controller I map all the data from the database into the API, into an array with these info:

```
return r.data.reduce((prev, current, i, all) => {
                        if (!prev.some(t => t.tableID === current.tableID)) {
                            const presencesForThisTableID = all.filter(p => p.tableID === current.tableID);
    let newTableOverview: Interfaces.TableOverview = {
                                tableID: current.tableID,
                                tableID_description: current.tableID_description,                                                                                                                       
                                presences: presencesForThisTableID.map(this.mapperService.mapApiMessageToTablePresence)
```

so this is part of the controller, in which I take all the data from the database, and I reduce all the infos 3 categories, the ID, the description and then all the sub-data for each table, 
This is done so I can see how many different tables there will be and generate one for each different ID, and THEN with a second ng-repeat inside the first one, I'll populate the tables accessing the data with "vm.presences.xxxx".

the htm code is like this:

```
    <div class="row topMargin-10" ng-repeat-start="t in vm.TableOverview">
<div class="panel-body noPadding">
                <table id="tableStyle" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="p in t.presences">
                        <td>{{p.month}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.day1}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.day2}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.day3}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.day4}}</td>
                        <td>{{p.day5}}</td>
```

and so on, so you get the idea, as you can see, X panel will be generated depending on how many different TableID I get from the database, and each table will be populated with another ng-repeat, now I want to assign a different color to EACH panel header that gets generated.

Comment: ng-class fits perfectly what you need https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: thank you for the answer, maybe I'm missing something cause I m new to angular, but I used ngClass in this project multiple times, but I don't know how to use it properly inside an ng-repeat, because the data created by the ng-repeat is never the same, so how can I assign classes without knowing what will be shown? could you provide me an example so I understand?

Comment: You have to take something which descrive the class in your array of objects. Then you can use it inside your ng-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="table in tables">
     <div ng-class="table.class">
       <!-- define your content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In the js and css you can define as many class as you wish

js example:

```
$scope.tables = 
 [
  {'name':'sea', 'class':'blueStyle', 'rows':4, ..},
  {'name':'mountain', 'class':'brownStyle', 'rows':3, ...}
];
```

css example:

```
.blueStyle
{ color: blue};

.brownStyle
{ color: brown};
```

edit:

In your case:

```
 var colors: ['blue','white','red','black'...]
 let newTableOverview: Interfaces.TableOverview = {
                                tableID: current.tableID,
                                tableID_description: current.tableID_description,
                                tableID_class:colors[tableID],
```

css:

```
 .white
    {
       background-color: white
    }
    .red
    {
        background-color: red
    }
```

html:

```
   <table id="tableStyle" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                       <th ng-class="t.tableID_class" >This is the table header</th>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="p in t.presences">
                        <td>{{p.month}}</td>
```

I supposed you want to take the colors from a simple js array declared before. But you could take it from wherever you wish.

Comment: I don't understand this example, I'll give you some random data, can you apply your example to that data so I understand?

Let's say I can have up to 10 different tables, each one needs a different css class to define the header color, how would I define that with your example?

Comment: I saw your edit, the problem is, in the htm file there is a default table template that get's populated with a ng-repeat-start, and for each different "ID" found in the database, it creates a table for it (up to 10id , so 10 possible tables" , an ID is accessed with: t.IDtable, and the value of the ID range from 0 to 9

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the code within your question so I can help you in a better way? I mean html and javascript. And tell me how should the program decide which color/style to use for each table

Comment: Should the color of the header be random or you should take the information from somewhere? Anyway the main idea is to put a "class name" inside each object that gets repeated (each element in vm.TableOverview in your case, lets say an tableID_class). After that, you can use it with ng-class='t.tableID_class'

Comment: not random, each different table should have one specific color for the panel header! let s say: tableID: 0 = blue, tableID:1 = red and so on

Comment: Edited, see if you can understand it in this way. I supposed you want to take the colors from a simple js array declared before. But you could take it from wherever you wish. Put em in the db or stuffs

Comment: thank you, I'll try your solution in the afternoon if I have time, otherwise tomorrow and I'll see if it works, but the logic behind makes sense so I guess it will! thank you for the help

Comment: You are welcome, remember to put the v tick if the problem is solved